# Is it possible to configure dynamic allowed options in Bitbucket Pipeline for Custom Deployment?

Tags: aws-lambda, bitbucket, pipeline, serverless, cicd

How to configure to dynamically fetch allowed-values from the available folder names in the branch?

Is it possible to configure dynamic dropdown's allowed-values in Bitbucket Pipeline for Custom Deployment?

```
  custom:     Deployment:
      - variables:
          - name: lambda_name 
            default: "choose an action"
            allowed-values:
              - "choose an action"
              - "my lambda 1"
              - "my lambda 2"
```

Comment: No, but you can use Bitbucket's REST API to trigger the pipeline by passing the values as a JSON payload. But this requires the removal of allowed-values attribute from the yaml and validating the inputs before you invoke the API.